# @description of @RestResource doesn't work

Tags: spring-data-rest

Here is project/Spring Data Rest version.

```
    // gradle
    springBootVersion = '2.4.2'
    springDependencyManagement = '1.0.10.RELEASE'
```

Here is my code:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "address", path = "address")
public interface AddressRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Address, Long> {

    @Transactional
    @RestResource(description = @Description("delete all addresses based on the given city"))
    Long deleteAllByCity(String city);
}
```

`address/search` **doesn't work**

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "deleteAllByCity" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/address/search/deleteAllByCity{?city}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/address/search"
    }
  }
}
```

`/profile/address` **doesn't work**

```
...
      {
        "name": "deleteAllByCity",
        "type": "SAFE",
        "descriptor": [
          {
            "name": "city",
            "type": "SEMANTIC"
          }
        ]
      }
...
```

**How can I add description into search and profile?**

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RestResource.html#description--), `RestResource.description` is the description of the collection resource, so it is not meant to describe a method, even though `@RestResource` can be put on method.

To add humen-readable string to a link in the response of `/address/search`,  create a file `src/main/resources/rest-messages.properties`, add a line `_links.deleteAllByCity.title=delete all addresses based on the given city`.  Then the `/address/search` response JSON should become

```json
{
  "_links" : {
    "deleteAllByCity" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/address/search/deleteAllByCity{?city}",
      "templated" : true,
      "title" : "delete all addresses based on the given city"
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/address/search"
    }
  }
}
```

## Reference

https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#mediatypes.hal.i18n